# SSIS and Netezza Fuzzy Looup

Tags: ssis, fuzzy, netezza

I am trying to connect to Netezza using SSIS , connection works fine but when I used Fuzzy look up get the table from Netezza it does not work. How do I know it does not work is because it shows the table but when I go to column mapping I don't see input and lookup column

Can somebody please help me if they encounter this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

From the [SSIS Documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137786.aspx):

> The transformation needs access to a reference data source that
>   contains the values that are used to clean and extend the input data.
>   The reference data source must be a table in a **SQL Server
>   database.**

Netezza does have a function to compute the [Levenshtein edit distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance): `le_dst`

You could use this to do your fuzzy lookups. You'd have to pick a distance that works for you.